# Sound won't stop when I go back to a previous Stage with code

Tags: actionscript-3, button, audio

i have 4 scenes and i put my script for music in scene 2 and then i jump to scene 3 but when i go back to scene 2 and press pause or stop, my music wont do that, but when i play, the music play and i get 2 music start :(, can anybody help the script ?

regards im newbie,

```
stop();

import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

//declaring all variables 
var isPlaying:Boolean = false;// boolean type of  variables can be true or false only
var myMusic = new soothing();// saving music in a varaible 
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();// sound channel Class  to stop
var lastPosition:Number = 0;

play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPlayClick);
pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPauseClick);
stop_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onStopClick);

function onPlayClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  if (isPlaying == false)
  {
    isPlaying = true;
    myChannel = myMusic.play(lastPosition);
}

myChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, completeHANDLER);
function completeHANDLER(event:Event):void
{
    lastPosition = 0;
    isPlaying = false;
}
}

function onPauseClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    isPlaying = false;
    lastPosition = myChannel.position;
    myChannel.stop();
}

function onStopClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (isPlaying == true)
    {
        isPlaying = false;
        lastPosition = 0;
        myChannel.stop();
    }
}

homebtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, qnextScene);

function qnextScene(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 2");
}
gallerybtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nxtScene);

function nxtScene(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 3");
}
mebtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextsScene);

function nextsScene(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 4");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh, yes, the infamous stage sound bug I spent four months chasing down.

One fix: DON'T GO BACKWARDS ON STAGES. They're quite buggy.

Instead, what you put on a given stage, instead put inside a MovieClip. Create two functions instead each of those major MovieClips, one to start all the sounds, animations, etc that need to happen when it appears. The other to STOP sounds, animations, etc.

Then, set up a SINGLE stage with code to swap between these.

One other issue you're going to run into when you start in on this approach is that variables will seemingly clear themselves spontaneously. This is due to the nature of the timeline.These master movieclips should have ONE FRAME ONLY, and stop(); must be the first line of code after the import. If you have multiple frames on these master movieclips, or if you neglect stop, things will keep re-initializing, which is a pain in the butt.

> (Heading this off at the pass: yes, code on the timeline is
>   acceptable, as long as all the code relates directly to the object it
>   is on the timeline OF. Pure code should be parked in the document
>   class and linked classes. The idea that you should never put code on
>   the timeline is a relic practice from AS2.)

Comment: i have a college task for making a website using actionscript 3, so the word "dont go backwards on stages" is impossible haha,

so what should i do now ? can you correct the script please ? btw sorry i can speak english to much haha

Comment: Hi. Nope. This is a bug in Flash itself. The stages will NOT work at all, end of story. I'm very sorry. You can copy and paste layers from timelines, by the way, but this will not work unless you follow the above method.

Comment: You can copy and paste layers from one timeline to another. It would only take a few hours to make this switch. I'd really recommend making a copy of your file and trying this.